# Regex to match filename in a url

Tags: regex, filenames

I'm wanting to remove any filenames from a url path (which doesn't contain the domain) in javascript.

The path would look like this:

```
/something/myfile.html?d=var
```

or

```
/something/myfile.html
```

and this is the desired output:

```
/something/
```

Sometimes urls get passed in like this:

```
/something/else
```

I don't want 'else' to be stripped out. In other words a regex that simply strips everything after the last slash would not work in my case.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I consider a filename anything with a . after a forward slash as seen above.

Comment: `else` is a valid file name.  Define what you consider a "file".

Comment: actually you can never be certain, what the url refers to (myfile.html does not need to stand for a file). urls are actually nothing else: urls. How they are served is a different question.

Comment: I think he means that if the last part of the url does not have a file type extension, he doesn't want it included. He's only wanting to see files with extensions. Is this right, @greatwitenorth?

Comment: Basically if the last part contains a filename (string containing a .) I want that entire filename stripped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that which matches the following regex pattern:

```
[^/?]*\.[^/?]*(\?.*)?$
```

or really

```
[^/?#]*\.[^/?#]*(\?.*)?(\#.*)?$
```

Don't forget to use `decodeURIComponent` on what's left.

Comment: yep that did it. The only thing I needed to do to make it work was escape the 2 forward slashes like so: [^\/?#]*\.[^\/?#]*(\?.*)?(\#.*)?$

Comment: You're confusing regex pattern and regex object constructor (which is not simply the pattern with `/` escaped).